# How to use XPath in Nokogiri to match strings using * pattern?

Tags: ruby, xml, xslt, xpath, nokogiri

I can not work out how to change this XPath query so it can search for any subdomain of `google.com` instead of having to specify every subdomain in the query.

```
(img|*//img)[contains(@src, '//')][not(contains(@src, 'test.google.com') or contains(@src, 'news.com'))]
```

I was expecting the `contains` matcher to recognise regex patterns like `*.google.com` but it doesn't seem to.

How should the above query look like so it can detect subdomains of a URL in image `src` attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `contains(@src, '.google.com')` It will do a case sensitive substring match on the src attribute . No need for a wild card